# New laptop adapter has 0.5A lower input?

Tags: laptop, battery, adapter

I'm buying a new adapter for my ASUS laptop, but its output is a little different than my old adapter.

**Old:**
Input - 100-240V, 2.0A, 50-60Hz
Output - 19V 3.42A

**New:**
Input - 100-240V, 1.5A, 50-60Hz
Output - 19V 3.42A

I know that the voltages must match, but does a little difference in the amperage matter? Will this harm my laptop in any way?

Thank you for help!

Comment: The output is the same, the difference is the input, i.e. how much current it drawns from the wall socket.
Same output of the adapter means same input into the laptop.

Answer (score 3):

The new one loses less power in its conversion.
The outputs are the same, so if those figures are accurate, the new one is more efficient.

Comment: The new adapter may feel cooler when operating than the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the input current (amperage) does not matter much, except that if it is much more than the output current, it uses more electricity (thus less efficient).

For the output current, it should be always (somewhat) more than the minimum current requirements of the device. If the adapter can deliver more current it's fine too, the device will not draw more than needed. However, the adapter should never deliver less otherwise either the adapter may stop working, start smoking or the device connected will not function correctly.

As you already noted the output voltage of the adapter and the input voltage of the device should be (almost) equal.